# Problems extracting text from pdfs in PYTHON

Tags: python, pdf, data-mining, text-mining, text-extraction

I'm doing a text extraction from some pdfs and return in the terminal what is the extracted text using python. However, there are some pdfs that are returning me instead of the text, special characters, or depending on the library codes used, such as (cid:1005)(cid:856)... . How can I resolve this?
I've already changed libraries, used sites to remove any password that the pdfs may have, I've opened them in Word, in Notepad and nothing. The problem still persists!
Libraries used: PDFMiner, PyPDF2, PyMuPDF and pdfplumber.

Comment: On the PDF files where this happens, are you able to cut and paste text out of those PDFs using a regular GUI PDF reader? They may just not actually contain the as text text, which can be stored as images instead.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the PDF library used in this answer.

Allow me first to explain why extracting text from a PDF is hard.

PDF is typically an unstructured document format. That is to say, a PDF document typically does not store information with regards to document structure (such as "this bounding box denotes a sentence" or "this bounding box denotes a row in a table").

Instead a PDF document typically contains postfix rendering operations.
In pseudo-code, you'd have something like:

- go to 80, 200
- set the active font to Helvetica
- set the stroke color to black
- draw the glyph for character "H"

There are tons of ways in which this could go wrong.
For instance, a font may provide a mapping that tells reader-software "the character with ID 105 should be mapped to Unicode symbol XX".

You can also include instructions explicitly to tell reader-software "this sequence represents the text XYZ".

You can also provide the name of a default mapping. Then the reader should know "I have glyph X, that should be Unicode symbol X".

All of these can be present, or none of them, or some of them. And they can contradict each other.

What ultimately ends up being extracted is down to heuristics in the reader-software. It may be something as naïve as "if this particular information is present, use it at all costs". It may be more clever such as "If this seems like a piece of text that makes sense in language X, use it".

Your document may simply be too "broken" to expect normal text to come out of it.

You can use the online tool from vera PDF. It's a checker that can tell you whether a PDF is broken. You can find it [here](https://demo.verapdf.org/).

You can also try to use `borb` to extract text from a PDF.

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the text on the first Page
    print(l.get_text()[0])
```

Comment: Joris, i copied this exact same code, i just changed the pdf path i'm using and it doesn't even show me what was extracted from the first page of the pdf. That is, the code only compiles but does not return anything.

Comment: Can you share the PDF?